# Migrate AIX 5.3 crypt function to C#

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, aix, des

I have a project that was on an old AIX system and we are migrating it to a new windows server system. I am trying to get a authentication system setup but I can't seem to match the way the password encryption was being created.

Can C# mimic the AIX [crypt](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.basetechref/doc/basetrf1/crypt.htm) function? I understand the function uses a form of DES, but I can't seem to set up the C# DES to match the outputs of the AIX crypt.

Comment: It seems that's just the unix `crypt` command, so you can probably grab the source code from elsewhere "These subroutines are provided for compatibility with UNIX system implementations."

Comment: @GregS: well, it seems he has tried stuff, the question becomes "where is the code?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick search for an implementation of the generic unix `crypt()` seems to point to an implementation at [code project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9183/A-C-implementation-of-Unix-crypt).

Note that this is just the generic Unix `crypt()` that AIX tries to emulate. It would be a good idea to test it against AIX code first, keeping in mind the specific encoding (character) encoding of the input and output parameters.

Comment: I won't be an ass and just answer "yes", as the C# programming language is Turing complete :)

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for. (Don't know why any of the google searches I've tried didn't bring this up.)